# Why doesn't this python 3.3 code work with yield?

Tags: yield, python-3.3

```
def main(i):
    while i > 0:
        if i == 5: yield i
        i -= 1
    print("ran")

main(10)
```

It doesn't print "ran", removing "yield i" fixes it but how do i format this correctly then?
The example on the lynda.com movie for python3 is identical, is there a syntactical difference between 3.3 and 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yield` is a magic keyword that turns the function into a generator.  That means that it's actually suspended at the `yield i` line, and you'll be able to resume execution in `main` when you consume that value.

Try replacing the last line with

```
it=main(10)
next(it) # = 5
next(it) # prints "ran", then raises StopIteration
```

Comment: I get it now thanks, i didnt really understand that the function needed to be called outside for it to keep turning. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome.  As I said, this is a generator, which is a way to sort of generate lists without making lists.  The general name for this kind of function — where execution passes back and forth until the yielding function is done — is a coroutine.